# How to calculate this approximation with no errors

Tags: javascript, python, php, math, approximation

I have a problem when I want to calculate the following:

Let's say that I have an online class for only 5 students. **The class costs **6000 NOK** per student.** I want to withdraw money every 5 seconds. If we calculate the cost for 5 seconds, we need to calculate the cost for one second which would be:

6000 NOK/3600 = 1.666666666666667 and let's approximate the result to 1.67 NOK per second.

So every 5 seconds I have to withdraw:

5x1.67 = 8.35 NOK

Let's say that the class lasted for 1 hour. That means 3600/5 = **720 times** I have to charge the students. I end up charging every student with this amount

720x8.35 = **6012 NOK**

So my question is that there is a difference between the initial cost of the class which is 6000 NOK, but in the end, I charged 6012 NOK from each student. How do I solve this issue when I write this in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use floating point if you can't stand for round-off error to be multiplied.

Comment: Don't round any of the numbers except when you display them to the user.